# Can't display the data entered in form in database

Tags: python, django, database, pycharm

The user enters the data in the form. But the data entered in the form doesn't get displayed in the Database.

views.py

```
def add(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=FilesCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request,'plagiarism/page1.html',{'form':FilesCreate()})
def add2(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form2=FilesCreate2(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
    return render(request,'plagiarism/page2.html',{'form':FilesCreate2})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class File1(models.Model):
    #user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    firstfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    #secondfile=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstfile
```

plagiarism/page1.html

```
<h1>Enter your first file</h1>
<form action="file2/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit file1"/>

    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

plagiarism/page2.html (displays page after clicking submit in page 1)

```
<h1>Enter your second file</h1>
<form action="plagiarism/file2/result/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
    <input type="submit" value="Get Results"/>

    {% endfor %}
    </form>
{% block h1 %}

    {% endblock %}
<body>
```

plagiarism/page3.html (displays page after clicking submit in page 2)

```
<h1> Here is your Result </h1>
    <h2>
        {{data}}
    </h2>
</body>
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from plagiarism.models import File1,File2
class FilesCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=File1
        exclude=()
        widgets={'firstfile':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':50,'rows':100})}
```

example.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def getresult(request):
    data=95.5
    return render(request,'plagiarism/page3.html',{'data': data})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from . import example3
urlpatterns=[

    url(r'^$',views.add,name='add'),
    url(r'file2/$',views.add2,name='add2'),
url(r'file2/result/$',example3.getresult,name='getresult')
]
```

Comment: Where are you displaying the data? But note that although you check the the form is valid, you don't tell the user if it isn't; or redirect away when it is. Presumably what's happening here  that the form is indeed not valid.

Comment: I want my data to enter database when the user enters text in the form. If the form is valid, when the user clicks submit, the page is redirected to another page (I was redirected to another page that  I've created when I entered data and clicked submit)

Comment: Can you show your `urls.py` file?

Comment: I hadn't read your code carefully, I thought you were uploading a file. You also need to show the view `add2`, since that's what's processing the form. But you don't need an additional view, you could process the form with `add`.

Comment: I've updated the code with all the details since some of you asked for. I don't want to upload any file. All I need to happen is the user should input data in the form and the inputted data should go to the database.

Comment: Well, now you'd have to show what the `FilesCreate2` form is, because that's what's processing when you submit. But you have a big mess there, that is hard to address in a comment, also because it's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do. I don't know why you have two views and two forms, and you are mixing them up.  Maybe carefully reading [the documentation on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) would help.

Comment: I suggest you to put an "else:" to that "form .is_valid" and check if the execution goes there. As Daniel Roseman said, maybe the form is not valid.

Comment: @jsanchezs That's one of the things that's missing, but it's more than that. The `action` for the first form is `file2`, so the `add` view will never process a `POST` request, and that's probably not what's intended (as well as the `action` in the second form, which is almost certainly wrong).

Comment: I haven't uploaded the FilesCreate2 here. I have written it in my code and I haven't displayed it here since it is similar to FilesCreate1 :) @PauloAlmeida

Comment: @charithareddy What do you mean by "similar"? Does it have a `firstfile` field? If it doesn't, it won't correctly process the view. (That would be a strange way to do it anyway, normally you want the same form to display the data and process it).

Comment: from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from plagiarism.models import File1,File2
class FilesCreate2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=File2
        exclude=()
        widgets={'secondfile':forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':50,'rows':100})}

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Your saying that add view will never process a POST request seems valid to me. Can you help me in writing the correct code?

Comment: @charithareddy I'll try to get you started, just a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a kind of wizard, where you process a form and it redirects you to the next, but you're not doing the basics of form processing well. For simple form handling, you can do this:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from . import example3

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.add,name='add'),
    url(r'file2/result/$', example3.getresult, name='getresult')
]
```

In the template, you are calling `file2` with the form's `action`, but you really want to call the same page, to process the form with the `add` view:

**plagiarism/page1.html**

```
<h1>Enter your first file</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{field}}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit file1"/>
</form>
```

Note the missing `action` attribute in the `<form>` element.

When you visit the root of the website, the `add` view will be called with a `GET` request. When you submit the form, the same `add` view will be called, with a `POST` request, which will then be processed:

**views.py**

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FilesCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('getresult'))
    else:
        form = FilesCreate()
    return render(request,'plagiarism/page1.html',{'form': form})
```

Note the `HttpResponseRedirect`, which redirects to a new page on success, and the `else`, which creates an empty form for the first time you visit the page (i.e. `request.method` is not `POST`, it is `GET`). This way, if the form isn't valid, the last line will render it bound to the data that was submitted and display the errors.

This *should* get you the data into the database, which was your first goal. If you want to go to another form upon submission, you can redirect there (instead of the result page) and do the same as above in the view `add2`.

There used to be a Django Form Wizard, but you can see [this project](https://github.com/django/django-formtools/) to do multi-step forms.