# How to convert Query set into a string?

Tags: python, django, database, django-forms, django-queryset

I have data in my database(named File1). I want to access the elements of the database and I wanted to use that data as strings. Further, I wanted to write that string into a file. But when I use File1.objects.all() I get a Query Set. I wanted the elements in the Query set as string.
 views.py

```
def getfile1(a):
    data=File1.objects.all()
    return data
```

example1.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='websitepc.settings'
import django
django.setup()
from plagiarism.views import getfile1
dbf1=getfile1(2)
print(dbf1)
exf1=dbf1.get()
print(exf1)
open("examplefile1.py", "w").close()
file = open("examplefile1.py", "w")
file.write(exf1)
```

My database consists of text (entered through a form, [for further understanding of how I entered data into database click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408730/cant-display-the-data-entered-in-form-in-database/49410570?noredirect=1#comment85823817_49410570))

The output I get is

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\sum\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/websitepc/plagiarism/example1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/websitepc/plagiarism/example1.py", line 16, in <module>
    file.write(exf1)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not File1
<QuerySet [<File1: abcd>]>
abcd

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can convert data to a string with `str()`. Anything you are able to use `get()` on will also return a string.

Comment: It worked. Thank you :)

Comment: Sure thing. You could have found this out with a simple google search though. Try not to ask questions until you are sure you are not able to find the answer on your own.

Comment: Of course, just converting a queryset to a string doesn't give you anything useful you can write to a file. Perhaps you want to serialize it to JSON?